# How to display data to input field after fetching data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am fetching data from an API and would like to know how to set that fetched date in input fields. its seems like an absolute beginner problem, anyhow kindly help me of this.

Here is my code:

```
export default function Consumerdetails() {

  const [consumer, getConsumer] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    httpClient(url + `/api/consumers`).then((res) => {
      console.log('Success:', res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('An error occurred:', err.res)
    });
  });

return (
<div>
<TextField
   required
   id="outlined-required"
   label="User Name"
   variant="outlined"
   name="username"
   value={consumer.username} onChange={getConsumer}
/>

<TextField
   required
   id="outlined-required"
   label="Phone Number"
   variant="outlined"
   name="phone"
   value={consumer.phone} onChange={getConsumer}
/>
</div>
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign api response to state and assign state to input fields.

```js
export default function Consumerdetails() {

  const [consumer, getConsumer] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    httpClient(url + `/api/consumers`)
    .then(res => res.json()
    .then((data) => {
        getConsumer(data);
    })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('An error occurred:', err.res)
    });
  },[]);

return (
<div>
<TextField
   required
   id="outlined-required"
   label="User Name"
   variant="outlined"
   name="username"
   value={consumer?.username} onChange={getConsumer}
/>

<TextField
   required
   id="outlined-required"
   label="Phone Number"
   variant="outlined"
   name="phone"
   value={consumer?.phone} onChange={getConsumer}
/>
</div>
})
```

Comment: i am facing error like ```An error occurred: undefined```

Comment: Sorry. There is typo. You can use getConsumer instead of setConsumer inside fetch.

Comment: Code Modified. Please check now.

Answer (score 2):

you can set API response data like this

```
export default function Consumerdetails() {
  const [consumer, setConsumer] = useState([]);

  // dummy json data
  const data = {
    username: "xyz",
    mobile: "123456789",
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // your api data
    setConsumer(data);
  }, []);

  const onChange = (event) => {
    // here set change value
    setConsumer(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        required
        id="outlined-required"
        label="User Name"
        variant="outlined"
        name="username"
        value={consumer.username}
        onChange={onChange}
      />

      <TextField
        required
        id="outlined-required"
        label="Phone Number"
        variant="outlined"
        name="phone"
        value={consumer.mobile}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes but same i'm facing error in input field, like "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')" form here ```value={consumer.username} onChange={setConsumer}```

Comment: @Joe can you send me your API response format here.

Comment: Yes.. i added my API response in my updated question. please check once

Comment: @Joe I updated the above code with dummy data you can follow same way it's work

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
  httpClient(url + `/api/consumers`).then((res) => {
    getConsumer(res.data) // you store the data
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  });
},[]);
```

Check if it is works for you

Comment: I store the data like you did, but i am facing error in input field, like "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')" form here ```value={consumer.username} onChange={setConsumer}```

Comment: you can console.log(consumer) after return statement with { } to see if you are taking back array of objects. in that case you cannot access the "username" value like this, need to access the specific index of object.

Comment: Ohkay.. i updated my question what i get my API response.. please check once